# Why does my model only predict one class when I run it through my webcam?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a model using the MNIST dataset, and when I test it using my own image it predicts the class properly.

After I finished making the model, I saved it as a .h5 file and I wrote a program to predict the model's output using my webcam.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
class_names = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
def predict_number(prediction_image):
    global model, class_names
    predictions = model.predict(prediction_image)
    #print(predictions)
    prediction_final = np.argmax(predictions)
    #print(prediction_final)
    #print(f"Prediction: {class_names[prediction_final]}")
    return class_names[prediction_final]

while True:
    ret, win = cam.read()
    window_resized = win[0:450, 0:350]
    cv2.rectangle(win, (100, 100), (250, 250), (255, 0, 0), 0)
    img = win[100:250, 100:250]
    im_resized = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im_resized_array = np.asarray(im_resized)
    im_resized_array = im_resized_array[:,:,0]
    im_resized_array = im_resized_array / 255
    final_image = np.reshape(im_resized_array, (1, 28, 28, 1))
    prediction = predict_number(final_image)
    image = cv2.putText(window_resized, str(prediction), (100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) 
    cv2.imshow("Camera", window_resized)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord(' '):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Whenever I run this code, the model keeps predicting "8" regardless of what I show it for some reason, but I'm sure that my model functions properly as when I test it using my own image taken from the same camera in the .ipynb form it properly predicts it.

I feel like there is an error with the way I'm saving/loading my model, or an error with how I'm processing the image.

I'm saving my model with:

```
model.save("model.h5")
```

Comment: `im_resized_array = im_resized_array[:,:,0]` takes only the blue channel of your image. You probably  want to convert to grayscale instead (with `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` for example).

Comment: Just tried this, it still only shows "8" on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this issue probably had something to do with the dataset and the way I was processing the image. I ended up using the dataset from `tfds` instead of `keras.datasets`:

```
dataset = 'mnist'
(img_train, label_train), (img_test, label_test) = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(dataset, split = ['train', 'test'], shuffle_files=True, batch_size=-1, as_supervised=True))

builder = tfds.builder(dataset)
info = builder.info

print(info.features["label"].names)
labels = info.features["label"].names

img_train = img_train / 255.0
img_test = img_test / 255.0
```

And then I changed the way I was processing the image before running `model.predict()` on it with:

```
image = cv2.imread(#image)
image = np.resize(image, (28,28,1))
image = np.array(image).astype('float32')
image = image.reshape(1,28,28,1)
image = image / 255
print(np.shape(image))
tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
pred = model.predict(image)
print(pred)
pred_index = np.argmax(pred)
print("Prediction: ", labels[pred_index])
```

This solved the issue, now the model at least *tries* to predict whatever image I give it through `cv2`

I think the way I was processing the image made `image` an empty numpy array, due to which it was predicting 8 every time regardless of what image I was using because it did not have any other option.